# Pandas read_gbq not working correctly?

Tags: python, mysql, google-bigquery

I am attempting to union two tables within a dataset on google BigQuery

using the following code:

```
def mergeTables(workingTable, table, DATASET_ID):
    query ="""
        SELECT
            full_name,
            age
        FROM {DATASET_ID}.{workingTable}
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT
            full_name,
            age
        FROM {DATASET_ID}.{table}
        LIMIT 100;
        """
    df = pd.read_gbq(query, "joe-python-analytics", 'standard')
    print(df)
```

working table and table are the two tables i wish to merge with my union operator. However when i run the method i get the error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/j/queries/job_aalt=json returned "Encountered "" at line 6, column 15.
[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]">
```

I have already enabled standard sql and this doesnt seem to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making the input explicit to Python, like so:

```
df = pd.read_gbq(query,
                 project_id="joe-python-analytics",
                 dialect='standard')
```

As you can see from the [method contract](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/gbq.py#L24), it expects sereval keyworded arguments so the way you used it didn't properly setup the standard dialect.